# Code unable to edit perms of an existing role

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to code a bot that edits the permission of the role "LFT" and makes its mentionable permission `false` when the Role is mentioned. However, the code does nothing. I just get a `DeprecationWarning`.

It'll be really great if someone could help me with this.

```js
let lftrole = message.guild.roles.find("name", "LFT");
if (message.content.includes('@LFT')) {

  lftrole.edit({
    mentionable: false
  });
  console.log(`Role mentionable: False`);

  .then(
    setTimeout(() => {
      let lftrole = message.guild.roles.find("name", "LFT");

      lftrole.edit({
        mentionable: true
      });
      console.log(`Role mentionable: True`);
    }, 30000)
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because you're checking if `message.content` contains `'@LFT'`: mentions are rendered as `@RoleName`, but to the bot they look like `<@&RoleID>`.
You could try to parse that pattern, but it would be way easier using [`Message.mentions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=mentions). I would do it like this:

```js
let lftrole = message.guild.roles.find("name", "LFT");

function changeRole(value = true) {
  lftrole.edit({
    mentionable: value
  });
  console.log(`LFT role mentionable: ${value}`);
}

if (message.mentions.roles.has(lftrole.id)) {
  changeRole(false);
  setTimeout(changeRole, 30000);
}
```

Note: the `DeprecationWarning` you're getting is from when you use [`Collection.find()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=find) to find the role. The non-deprecated way makes you use a function that returns whether an element is acceptable: in this way you can combine more criteria. Here's how:

```js
// Instead of using:
let role = guild.roles.find("name", "myRole");

// You can use:
let role = guild.roles.find(r => r.name == "myRole");
// This is useful when you want to check for multiple things, 
// or if you want to use other variables from your code
let role = guild.roles.find(r => {
  if (otherVariable) return r.name == "myRole";
  else return r.name == "myRole" && r.mentionable;
});
```

Comment: Happy to hear that :)